# Where do component styles go after ng build?

Tags: angular-cli

Updating to Angular 11 has introduced a bug where one of my CSS styles is having its opacity changed from 100% to 1%. It looks like the build process is doing this as if I run my app locally without building, the style is correct. But then after building the style is changed.

I have just tried to find the styling in `styles.css` in my dist folder after running `ng build`, to find that the style is nowhere to be seen. I have checked for other component styles as well, but none of them are present in `styles.css`. However all of angular material's styling is there.

If I look in the browser, and click the link in dev tools to find the file where the changed style is, it's present in some `<style>` tags in the head of my index file. Which are obviously being injected into index.html from somewhere.

So where is this somewhere? Where exactly do all of the app component's styles go after running ng build?

```
Angular: 11.2.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1102.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1102.3
@angular-devkit/core               11.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics         11.2.3
@angular/cdk                       11.2.3
@angular/cli                       11.2.3
@angular/material                  11.2.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   11.2.3
@schematics/angular                11.2.3
@schematics/update                 0.1102.3
rxjs                               6.6.6
typescript                         4.1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The styles go into the `main-es... .js` files in the `/dist` folder after `ng build`. And if you look at the dom in your browser when running a built app, you will see your styles in one of the `<styles>` tags in the `<head>`.

As for your opacity issue, I suppose `ng build` could be changing the order of styles, so you could try making it `!important`; or if you add something like `div.my-style { ...` instead of `.my-style { ...`, it ups the importance.

It could also be that css `opacity` is from range `0.0` to `1.0`, if you happen to be trying to use percentages instead.

Comment: So I thought this as well, but I've tried adding both more specific styles and `!important` and it doesn't fix the issue. `mat-icon.autocomplete-icon {
 margin-right: 10px;
 opacity: 100% !important;
 color: #066b92;
 font-size: 21px;
}`

Comment: The `opacity` property ranges from `0.0` to `1.0`, so `opacity: 1.0` should be fully opaque/ fully visible. Maybe the percent is confusing it.